# IntelliJ IDEA with Maven not highlighting Kotlin warnings

Tags: maven, kotlin, intellij-idea

I have a Kotlin Maven project and somewhere I have this code:

```
fun getSomeData() : List<String>? {
  return emptyList();
}
```

IntelliJ should indicate that return type should be `List<String>`, not `List<String>?` because it is never null. But it doesn't.

I'm using Kotlin 1.4.20:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
  <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.20</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: First check power save mode. If power save mode on it doesn't work. Then click re-import project on maven panel.

Comment: Power save mode is disabled.

Comment: Do you have "redundant nullable return type" inspection enabled?